# how to guarantee data integrity in action class

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, struts, data-integrity

I have a 3 layer web application which uses these frameworks: struts, spring and hibernate.
in action class I have called a method in business logic layer which update data in a specific table. now I have to call another class to insert data in another table, these are different tables so have different classes in business logic layer and DAO layer. I want to have data integrity means if the second insert failed, I have to rollback the first one. how could I control it in action class.

```
try{
            policyIssuanceManagement.updatePolicy(currentPolicy);
            String result=policyDetailManagement.insertDataInPolicyDetail(policyId, riskAmount, riskPercent, riskId, regionRisk, regionPercent, regionId, stepped, steppedPercent, steppedId, discount, discountPercent, discountId);

            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

I can not roll back the updated policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote 3 layer web application then I expect you application has service layer that implements with spring.So you should control your transaction into service layer using `@Transational` annotation inject in your service class.See sample service class

```
@Service
@Transational
public class PolicyManagement {
     @Transaction
     public void fooManagemantService() {
         policyIssuanceManagement.updatePolicy(currentPolicy);
         policyDetailManagement.insertDataInPolicyDetail(policyId, riskAmount, riskPercent, riskId, regionRisk, regionPercent, regionId, stepped, steppedPercent, steppedId, discount, discountPercent, discountId);
     }
}
```

This `declarative transaction` will rollback when one of the services method has failed.Don't forget to declare your spring-bean.xml or yourConfig.xml into

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>
```

Here is the [link](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/09/spring-declarative-transactions-example.html) for some reference.